# how to put array of user control in the columns of Grid

Tags: silverlight

Hi I have array of Employee data which includes photo,description, title name,salary. I have to show each employee data in separate panel control structure that means if I have 10 employees there will be 10 panels. and I have to show these panels  in a grid which has two columns. Also width of the panel in each column will vary according to main page size.

Comment: Why Two columns?  What should happen if there are more employees that will fit in the window?

Answer (score 0):

Why not represent the employee data with a separate userControl then use a Wrap panel to display the employees. This approach would handle a variable number of employees.

To better illustrate my idea here's some code:

The MainPage has a grid with a WrapPanel that fills the available space.

MainPage.xaml

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ct="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="WhiteSmoke">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ct:WrapPanel x:Name="panel1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                      Background="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
  public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler( MainPage_Loaded );
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded ( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            for ( int x = 0; x <= 10; x++ )
            {
                panel1.Children.Add( new ChildControl() );
            }
        }
    }
```

I am adding ChildWindow controls as defined below to show how the WrapPanel adapts the presentation of its children to the space available.

ChildWindow.xaml

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.ChildControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Width="100"
    Height="100">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="PowderBlue">
        <TextBlock Text="ChildControl"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If I've missed your point please give some more clarification.

Comment: I did exactly same. I want to utilize whole space of the main page but using wrap panel with horizontal orientation I am unable to do so. Space to the right side of the main page get wasted if size of the main page changes.

Comment: Is there any other way instead of using wrap panel?

Comment: I don't want to set columns width as fixed in layoutRoot. columns width will vary according to page so MyCustomControl's width should vary according to that.